How to calculate roundtrip-time using JMeter and AMQP Plugin?
I would like to test my RabbitMQ implementation with JMeter. For my test, the time that a message needs from the publisher to the consumer is interesting.
Is it possible to calculate this with JMeter? So far I have not found anything that gives me these values.
I know that I can specify ${\__time()} in the message from the publisher, which gives the time when the message was created. But that doesn't help me.
Here is a picture of what my test plan currently looks like:


Maybe you should use something unique like __UUID() function or combination of current timestamp with the number of virtual user (can be obtained using __threadNum() function) and current iteration
Once done you can wait for the given message in the consumer using While Controller and put everything under the Transaction Controller to get end-to-end processing time
